# Default number of players in a turn-based game? (OS X)

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, game-center

### Q: How do we set the default number of players?

---

#### **Let's create a GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController with a match request:**

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [GKMatchRequest new];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = [GKMatchRequest maxPlayersAllowedForMatchOfType:GKMatchTypeTurnBased];
request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2;


GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *controller = [GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController.alloc initWithMatchRequest:request];
controller.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;

[GKDialogController sharedDialogController].parentWindow = self.view.window;
[[GKDialogController sharedDialogController]presentViewController:controller];
```

### **Expected: 2 default players**

[image: Expected]

### **Actual: 16 default players**

[image: Actual]

## **GKMatchRequest Class Reference**

A GKMatchRequest object is used to specify the parameters for a new live or turn-based match. You initialize a match request object, then pass it to another object to actually create the match. The kind of object you pass it to depends on which kind of match you want and whether you want to display the standard matchmaking user interface.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger defaultNumberOfPlayers
```

The default number of players for the match.

If this property is not set, then the default number of players is equal to the value stored in the maxPlayers property. The default number of players determines the number of invitees shown in the standard matchmaking user interface. The player can choose to override this to add or remove slots.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the match correctly?  All docs I have read use `GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];` to initiate a match.

Comment: new is a combination of alloc and init. http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/new

Comment: How about defining `maxPlayers` using an integer as opposed to a `GKMatchRequest` object.  I believe that the max for turn-based games is 16 players.

Comment: It's interesting to note that in the [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKMatchRequest/defaultNumberOfPlayers) the `defaultNumberOfPlayers` property only became available in iOS 6, which suggests it is a new feature. I realise in the OS X documentation it is listed with the same availability as everything else, but perhaps the documentation is incorrect or the property exists, but the actual functionality hasn't been implemented yet. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Set **defaultNumberOfPlayers** to the value you desire.  In this case, it is set to match the minimum number of players.

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;               

    presentingViewController = viewController;

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init]; 
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers;     
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
    request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = minPlayers;

    GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];    
    mmvc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;
    mmvc.showExistingMatches = YES;

    [presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```